# Rounding to two decimals for an average value in a Pivot in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I would like to pivot the following query:

```
SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice)
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID;
```

And turn it into

```
Per Category        1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8

Average 
Unit 
Price           37.98   23.06   25.16   28.73   20.25   54.01   32.37   20.68
```

Answer (score 1):

How about calculating the average in the source query?
And then cast/convert it to a decimal while at it.

```
SELECT 
 'Average Unit Price' AS [Per Category], Pvt.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT CategoryID, CAST(AVG(UnitPrice) AS DECIMAL(16,2)) as AvgUnitPrice
  FROM dbo.Products
  WHERE CategoryID BETWEEN 1 AND 8
  GROUP BY CategoryID
) AS Src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(AvgUnitPrice)
  FOR CategoryID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]) 
) AS Pvt
```

Comment: @MousaAkkar if an answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.